# Skipping Google search results that point to certain sites

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, url

I have the following code that will skip certain URLs if needed:

```
SEARCH = "inurl:index.php?id="

def get_urls
  puts "Searching for possible SQL vulnerable sites, using search query #{SEARCH}"
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.user_agent = @user_agent
  page = agent.get('http://www.google.com/')
  google_form = page.form('f')
  google_form.q = "#{SEARCH}"
  url = agent.submit(google_form, google_form.buttons.first)
      url.links.each do |link|
        if link.href.to_s =~ /url.q/
          str = link.href.to_s
          str_list = str.split(%r{=|&})
          urls = str_list[1]
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == 'webcache.googleusercontent.com'
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == 'search.clearch.org'
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == 'duckfm.net'
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == 'search1.speedbit.com'
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == 'yoursearch.me'
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == 'search.speedbit.com'
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[1] == 'ads/preferences?hl=en'
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == 'www.sa-k.net'
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == 'github.com'
          next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == 'stackoverflow.com'
          urls_to_log = URI.decode(urls)
          puts "Site found: #{urls_to_log}"
          sleep(1)
          File.open("#{PATH}/SQL_sites_to_check.txt", 'a+') { |s| s.puts("#{urls_to_log}'") }
        end
      end
  puts "Possible vulnerable sites dumped into #{PATH}/SQL_sites_to_check.txt"
end
```

Is there a better more readable, less smelly, way to write the `next if`'s?

Comment: instead of `str_list[1].split('/')[2]` 100 times, just assign `str_list[1].split('/')[2]` to a variable.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth But then I'd still have to use the variable 100 times.

Comment: that's true, but you won't be executing a split that many times. You can also create an array of websites and just make sure that the variable(your URL) isn't in that array. Unfortunately I don't know ruby so I can't give you a complete answer.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth Well, I guess I'll just stick with it as is for now, and figure something out, thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be referring to the same information `str_list[1].split('/')[2]` several times. I highly suggest you simply do this one type and assign it to a variable so that your list can go

```
next if url == "github.com"
next if url == "google.com"
```

Not only is this clearer, but it should save time because splits are probably not the thing you wanna do 16 times in a loop.

Also right at the top you have `urls = str_list[1]` but then you don't use that variable??

Comment: Yeah, totally forgot the url variable while I was writing this haha. Should I save them to a variable or an array?

Comment: Also if I didn't do the splits, I'd have to add the http:// to the beginning of the URL wouldn't I?

Comment: And figure out if it was `https` or `http`

Comment: You should probably be using a regular expression then

Comment: @Tom Elaborate please?

Comment: If you are having trouble finding https or http or urls in general you can write a regular expression and compile it once and maybe have an easier time extracting urls something like "(https?://)?(www.)?[A-Za-z_0-9\-\:\?#@%&\*!~]+?(.com|.org|.net)(/[A-Za-z_0-9\-\:\?#@%&\*!~]*?\.)*"

Comment: @Tom It's not that I'm having trouble finding the `http`;`https` it's I don't want them output if they match the `next if`'s